# What is the Reputation cap?

Tags: support

What is the cap on reputation gained? Is it set on a daily basis? It doesn't really bother me either way, just curious on how this is determined. Check out Feb 21st for me:

[image: Image of my rep earned]

It is weird because I get upvotes on a few things and I didn't receive any reputation for it, but then later that night I got an accept on a question that did give points but the upvotes of that question didn't give any rep. Is there any documentation that points out how reputation is given and how it is capped?

Comment: The short explanation, would be that +15 accept answer rep is except from the cap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a daily cap as discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63327/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap). Many prolific users hit it easily every day; any overage is lost.

**Update**

I found the reputation FAQ - [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for. It doesn't bother me to not get the rep, just wasn't sure how it worked since on that day at least it seemed to stop at a random point. Thanks for the help.